# C# use of unassigned local variable on three variables

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a code that allows me to calculate the price of two products however there are some changes throughout the code, (I want to aplly discounts according to the volume that will be bought. However when I make counts with three variables it show use of unassigned local variable...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double peso_morango, peso_maca, total;
    double totalmorango, totalmaca, final_real;
    const double percentual = 0.1;

    Console.WriteLine("Insira a quantidade de morangos, em kg: ");
    peso_morango = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Insira a quantidade de maça, em kg:");
    peso_maca = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    if (peso_morango <= 5)
    {
        totalmorango = 2.50 * peso_morango;


    }
    else if (peso_morango > 5)
    {
        totalmorango = 2.20 * peso_morango;
    }
    else if (peso_morango > 8)
    {
        totalmorango = 1.62 * peso_morango;
    }
    else if (peso_maca <= 5)
    {
        totalmaca = 1.62 * peso_maca;
    }

    else if (peso_maca > 5)
    {
        totalmaca = 2.20 * peso_maca;
    }
    else if (peso_maca > 8)
    {
        totalmaca = 1.35 * peso_maca;
    }
    else if (peso_maca + peso_morango > 8)
    {
        total = totalmorango + totalmaca;

        final_real = (total) - (percentual * total);

        Console.WriteLine(" O valor final é de {0} euros", final_real);
    }
    else if (totalmaca + totalmorango > 25)
    {

        total = totalmorango + totalmaca;

        final_real = (total) - (percentual * total);

        Console.WriteLine(" O valor final é de {0} euros", final_real);
    }
    else if (peso_maca + peso_morango < 8)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" O valor final é de {0} euros", final_real);
    }

    else if (totalmorango + totalmaca < 25)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" O valor final é de {0} euros", final_real);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Where is the error indicated?  Where do you assign a value to that variable before trying to use it?

Comment: Most of this code is unreachable: either the first or second condition will always evaluate to true rendering the other else/if useless

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes/

Comment: The problem is in code construction. You have everywhere "else". This will cause, that only the first two condition will be executed. No other condition will ever be executed in this code. The compiler/environment do not test this and only detect, that there is at least one *(theoretically)* possible way, where the values are not set *(even when the will never be executed)*.

Comment: @LennartStoop: That doesn't make it unreachable in language terms. There's a big difference between "Execution will never reach here" and "The compiler can prove (with the rules in the specification) that execution *can* never reach here"

Answer (score 0):

`totalmorango` and `totalmaca` are not initialized, they are just declared. You need to initialize your variables with proper Initial values first before you use it.

By looking into your code, you are using them in addition operation.

assuming if any `if` `elseif` are not satisfy (where you assign value to them), you need them to be 0. (also it is unit value for addition operation)

replace your line

`double totalmorango, totalmaca, final_real;`

with

`double totalmorango = 0, totalmaca = 0, final_real = 0;`

**Update**

however whatever error you are facing will be solved by above steps, but as mentioned by others too. your checking ,

`else if (peso_morango > 5)`

is not appropriate if you want to check if value of `peso_morango` is greater than 5 but also if you want that to be less or equal to 8.
you should be checking `else if (peso_morango > 5 && peso_morango <= 8)`

And also you should be having separate condition checking for `peso_maca` . like,

```
        if (peso_maca <= 5)
        {
            totalmaca = 1.62 * peso_maca;
        }
        else if (peso_maca > 5 && peso_maca <= 8)
        {
            totalmaca = 2.20 * peso_maca;
        }
        else// no need to check else part "peso_maca > 8" as it always be true
        {
            totalmaca = 1.35 * peso_maca;
        }
```

and same way, separate condition checking for later part too.

By doing this, you will not even need to do,

`double totalmorango = 0, totalmaca = 0, final_real = 0;`

as suggested in first part of answer.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is not a solution to your problem, but the only part of the code which will run is:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double peso_morango, peso_maca, total;
        double totalmorango, totalmaca, final_real;
        const double percentual = 0.1;

        Console.WriteLine("Insira a quantidade de morangos, em kg: ");
        peso_morango = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Insira a quantidade de maça, em kg:");
        peso_maca = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (peso_morango <= 5)
        {
            totalmorango = 2.50 * peso_morango;
        }
        else if (peso_morango > 5)
        {
            totalmorango = 2.20 * peso_morango;
        }
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

This is because EITHER peso_morango <= 5 OR peso_morango > 5 will be true.
I don't think "else if" does what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 0):

To make such mistake means that you're a beginner in programming and you'll probably do with some explanation to what is happening.

We gonna use **int** for this example.

When you declare variable like this `int x;` that is basically say hey i need some memory allocate some for me, How much of memory depend on the [int](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/integral-types-table)

Now if you ever done some C++ or any unmanaged programming languages (Means the compiler doesn't do half of the work for you), you would understand that

`int x;` in memory will actually be holding some values from previous operations we don't know about, So you'll have to explicitly clean it from that garbage.

In C# that is basically the same, however here we have the compiler complaining to help you out, since you want some memory it needs to be fresh so you'll have to zero it out `int x = 0;`

So you'll have to zero it out or assign it a value you want to start with, you can use negative values too if you want to keep the zero, depending on the Valuetype `int or uint etc...`.